# Get Data-dir value from jQuery and pass it to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I'm coping with a problem I can't figure out.

I'm creating a menu for my website where I get all the values out of te database. I have four items: "Nintendo", "Playstation", "XBOX" and "PC". Each one of them has an unique ID. When one of the items are clicked on, I want to get that unique ID back.

With this piece of code get my values printed out on my website:

```
echo "<ul class=\"main_menu\">"; 

            while($names = $get_category_names->fetch_object())
            {
                echo "<li data-dir=" . $names->id . ">" . $names->name . "</li>";


            }

                echo "</ul>";
```

The part "li data-dir = names"  is not working as expected. I console.log my values in jquery but I get the same ID back, which is 1. But, when I check Firebug, I see that I do get what I want, but this should probably be because HTML counts 4 li elements:

```
<li data-dir="1">Nintendo</li>
<li data-dir="2">Playstation</li>
<li data-dir="3">Xbox</li>
<li data-dir="4">PC</li>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var main_menu = $('ul.main_menu');
    var sub_menu = $('ul.sub_menu');

    sub_menu.hide();

    var find_li = main_menu.find('li');

    main_menu.on('click', function()
    {
        //sub_menu.fadeIn(200);
        find_li.data('dir');
        console.log(find_li.data('dir'));

    })



});
```

Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Thanks a bunch.

Edit: The solution to this question is below. I did not understand my code good enough to look at the right places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `find_li` is a list of `li`s which is probably why the data is not working

if you try something like this it should work:

```
var lis = main_menu.find('li');

lis.click(function()
{
    //sub_menu.fadeIn(200);
    var dir = $(this).data('dir');
    console.log(dir);

})
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I understand now where it went wrong!